# how to replace object at particular index in nsmutablearray which contains multiple value at each index

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

My array contain (firstName,lastName,  age) at each index. now I want to change age of a person at index 1. please guide how to do it. Here is my code.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
productArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Adeem";
personObj.lastName = @"Basraa";
personObj.age = @"5";

[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Ijaz";
personObj.lastName = @"Ahmed";
personObj.age = @"10";

[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Waqas";
personObj.lastName = @"Ahmad";
personObj.age = @"15";
[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];
```

}

Comment: By using key value you can replace the content at any index of nsmutable array.

Comment: you're missing some info regarding the structure…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Person *person = (Person *)[myArray objectAtIndex:1];
person.age = 2;
```

Assuming `Person` is your custom object stored in the array

Comment: creepy - same type. same name. same age :)

Comment: well you win .. you posted before me :)

Comment: actually, you beat me by 1 minute. i'll delete mine =)

Answer (score 4):

use this

> ```
> [arrname replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:13]];//13 is the age you want to change
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `NSMutableDictionary` to save name,age,phone,address and add this dictionary to your array.

```
[[arry objectAtIndex:1] setObject:@"value" forKey:@"key"];
```

Like this you can change value.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   -insertObject:atIndex: or replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
productArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Adeem";
personObj.lastName = @"Basraa";
personObj.phoneNumber = @"123456789";

[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Ijaz";
personObj.lastName = @"Ahmed";
personObj.phoneNumber = @"987654321";

[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];

PersonDetail *personObj = [[PersonDetail alloc] init];
personObj.firstName = @"Waqas";
personObj.lastName = @"Ahmad";
personObj.phoneNumber = @"45656789";
[productArray addObject:personObj];
[personObj release];
}

- (void)change {

for (int i=0;i<[productArray count];i++) {
          PersonDetail *personObj = (PersonDetail *)[[productArray objectAtIndex:i] retain];
          personObj.phoneNumber = @"New";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your `NSMutableArray` consists of `NSMutableDictionary` objects,

**try something like this :**

```
NSMutableDictionary* entry = [entries objectAtIndex:index];

[entry setValue:@"newAge" forKey:@"Age"];
```